# Why is this a “Brilliant Move”?

Tags: engines, analysis

I don’t understand why chess.com says this is a “Brilliant Move”? Can someone explain please?

[image]

Comment: Did you try clicking "**Show Moves**" ?

Answer (score 5):

Whites bishop on g5 is hanging, after Bxg5 Nxg5 Qxg5 black is up a piece. However this would remove the defense of the c7 pawn allowing for Nxc7 by white forking the king and the rook on a1 leading to the winning of the exchange. Chess.com grants brilliancies when a move loses material but either maintains or creates an advantage.

Comment: That's a good analysis. But what if the knight lurking for forking on king is pushed away by `a6` first. Then both the knights hang and one will be lost.

Comment: @iammilind then you simply take with the bishop first, threatening the queen and then you can move the knight afterwards

Answer (score 0):

The move 8. e3 moves the pawn from e2 and allows the queen a clearer path to black's (undefended) knight on h5.  Piggy-backing of Bansel's analysis 8... Bxg5 9. Nxg5 Qxg5, black is now open to the Nxc7 fork.  However, if black doesn't play 9... Qxg5, the knight on h5 is now hanging because the queen on d1 has a clear path to h5.  Even worse for black, That h5 knight has no square to retreat to, in part to the f4 square being defended by our hero pawn on e3.

In short, 8. e3 indirectly threatens the h5 knight and forces black to either concede it, or give up the fork/exchange.

Comment: Hmm. Yes, Black can't ignore the threats entirely. But what if Black, instead of taking the bishop and giving the White knight a free move, simply plays g6 to give the knight a square? If White plays Bxe7, then Qxe7 would still leave c7 protected by the queen. Or is that simply positionally bad?

Comment: After 8... g6 9. Bh6 the knight's escape square of g7 is covered and really makes it hard for black to ever castle kingside.